# How to manually mount an encrypted filesystem under Linux Mint

Tags: linux, encryption, filesystems, partitioning, linux-mint

I have a problem on Linux Mint. It seems that the partition containing my home folder is full. This partition is encrypted... This prevents me from starting Cinnamon (because it tries to write in a file). For this reason, I use a live distribution to try to mount it and free some space in it but I have the following error:

```
$ sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sda4 /media/crypto/ -oencryption=aes-256
Password: 
ioctl: LOOP_SET_STATUS: Invalid argument
```

Any ideas?
Thanks very much for your help!
Thierry

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=manually+mount+encrypted (49 items) may help. Good luck.

Comment: How is the partition encrypted? LUKS? Tried using `cryptsetup` to open it?